# "node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080 throw err; ^"

Tags: javascript, node.js, compiler-errors, throw

I'm getting the following error in the console:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Sayan\OneDrive\Desktop\project prac\node\index.js'   
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.16.1
```

What should I do ?

Already tried :
Delete the `node_modules` directory
Delete the `package-lock.json` file
Run `npm install`

Also tried :
created a new folder and did the same

Comment: try npm cache clean --force

Comment: Solved , after reinstalling all the packages and changing the files directory .

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The error message reads: 'Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Sayan\OneDrive\Desktop\project prac\node\index.js.' This usually indicates that you are attempting to run the 'node' command from a different directory or that the file 'index.js' does not exist in the specified directory. In my case I was trying to run it on folder above my 'index.js' folder.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because there is a space in path like:
C:\Users\DELL\Documents\web development\nodejs\basic>
Here, in the path of directory there is a space "web development" try to remove this space by rename.
Or you can rename this to "web_development".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was wrong *name of index file*: **index,js**
After fixing it, the errors are gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know What module you had installed, but in my case when I use json-server

I got same error when used json-server
I had tried many way like

- remove node_module and package.json but didn't work
- I use json-server lastest with 1.0.0-alpha.21 So I think that I must update node and npm version but still didn't work

So I try don't use lastest 1.0.0-alpha.21 and change to "json-server": "^0.17.4" It work well
In node project I do

- npm uninstall json-server   (remove package json-server)
- npm install json-server@0.17.4 (install with specify version)